# How to reference date as column name in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

The following 4 fields I have created in mysql table:

```
NAME    2018-06-08  2018-06-09  2018-06-10
suresh     P            NULL        A
```

When I want to update particular column, say:

```
update simpletest SET 2018-06-09='A' WHERE NAME='suresh

NAME    2018-06-08  2018-06-09  2018-06-10
suresh     P            NULL        A
```

It shows an error like:

> *2018-06-09* not consider as a field;

How can it be accepted as field while creating? 
Provide the solution, please

Comment: try adding backticks e.g. `SET \`2018-06-09\` =` . But to be honest if you find yourself adding dates as column names you need to re-think your database design. This is not scalable and is almost certainly not properly normalised. Every time you need a new date you do not want to have to add a new column...your schema should not change just to add new data, that is a violation of relational design principles. Also it makes it very hard to write a query e.g. to get figures for different dates.

Comment: Please fix the schema first. How many columns are you going to create, as the number of dates increase. RDBMS is not a Spreadsheet.

Comment: Study database normalisation and entity-relationship design and hopefully you'll understand how to structure it correctly. Probably all the data in these date columns should actually be in a second table which has a foreign key back to the first one. e.g. the second table would have columns `"username", "date", "value"`, and a row in that table would look like `"suresh", "2018-06-08", "P"`, then the next row would be `"suresh", "2018-06-09", NULL`, etc. Then the "simpletest" table would just have the "name" field and any other static details directly about the user e.g. email, phone etc.

Comment: thanks for your answers; I can understand my schema is problem as per the requirements i planned and done; Let me change entire structure and we can share the good results;

Answer (score 0):

I think, using backticks will do the necessary,

```
update simpletest SET `2018-06-09`='A' WHERE NAME='suresh';
```